# How's Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, vertices

so I tried Blender 2.8 beta when it launched but went back to 2.79b because there were some functions not working properly or maybe I didn't know how to do it. What got me frustrated was aligning two vertices in blender 2.8. I know how to do it on 2.79 but in 2.8 didn't work for me. Someone told me because 2.8 is is in beta they are still trying to figure out some functions within the program. So I wanted to see if there were major improvements from when 2.8 beta launched until now. I hope it does because I love how 2.8 looks and I really want to try EEVEE.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I also prefer 2.79 to 2.8 in terms of modeling. Since files made with 2.8 cannot be opened with 2.79, that mean I have to wait for stable release

Comment: 2.79 seems stable with functions and handling files from the same software but I feel 2.8 is the next big thing so better get used to it now and be ready for the full release. (Personal Opinion) So far I've been enjoying blender 2.8, I kinda struggled finding the functions I used in 2.79 but Andrew Pierce's tutorial videos helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A lot has changed since 2.8 Beta was first released - it is far more stable and consistent that it was in the early days. I would suggest (if you can't wait for the official release of the final version - most likely in July) that you download the latest version and give it a try.

Comment: Yes a lot has changed and I dont have the same issues I had when it released. The alignment function works properly now instead of having a big gray square. It seems the archipack isnt working yet but not a problem at all. So far I've been having fun with blender 2.8. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes Blender 2.8 still in BETA but don't miss out on it because is a great improvement in many ways. I recommend to check this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPVpg4_POww. Andrew Price does a pretty good job explaining the changes. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I've been following Andrew Price blender tutorial videos and his Blender 2.8 interface tutorial has helped me a lot. I pretty much learned how to model from him. He is a good teacher lol